# "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" Error on my program

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

Whenever I click on my retry button on my app, it throws me out of the app and back to the AppDelegate.

Entire Code(It's a lot, I know)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var gameOver: UIImageView!

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) { //What Happens After you click the "Play" button

    tapsValid = true
    ballChange = true
    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = false
    self.logo.isHidden = true
    self.Play.isHidden = true
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true
    scoreOnBoard.isHidden = true
    highScoreOnBoard.isHidden = true
    scoreLabel.isHidden = false

    self.Ball.center.x = 178.0
    self.Ball.center.y = 390.0
    self.pillar.center = CGPoint(x: 175.0,y: 436.0)
    self.pillar2.center = CGPoint(x: 214.0,y: 407.0)
    self.pillarTop2.center = CGPoint(x: pillar.center.x, y: pillar.center.y-35)
    self.pillarTop3.center = CGPoint(x: pillar2.center.x, y: pillar2.center.y-35)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.045, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.movement), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    self.pillar3.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar2.center.x, y: pillar2.center.y)
    self.pillar4.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar3.center.x, y: pillar3.center.y)
    self.pillar5.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar4.center.x, y: pillar4.center.y)
    self.pillar6.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar5.center.x, y: pillar5.center.y)
    self.pillar7.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar6.center.x, y: pillar6.center.y)
    self.pillar8.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar7.center.x, y: pillar7.center.y)
    self.pillar9.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar8.center.x, y: pillar8.center.y)
    self.pillar10.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar9.center.x, y: pillar9.center.y)
    self.pillar11.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar10.center.x, y: pillar10.center.y)
    self.pillar12.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar11.center.x, y: pillar11.center.y)
    self.pillar13.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar12.center.x, y: pillar12.center.y)
    self.pillar14.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar13.center.x, y: pillar13.center.y)
    self.pillar15.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar14.center.x, y: pillar14.center.y)
    self.pillar16.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar15.center.x, y: pillar15.center.y)
    self.pillar17.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar16.center.x, y: pillar16.center.y)
    self.pillar18.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar17.center.x, y: pillar17.center.y)
    self.pillar19.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar18.center.x, y: pillar18.center.y)
    self.pillar20.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar19.center.x, y: pillar19.center.y)
    self.pillar21.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar20.center.x, y: pillar20.center.y)
    self.pillar22.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar21.center.x, y: pillar21.center.y)
    self.pillar23.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar22.center.x, y: pillar22.center.y)
    self.pillar24.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar23.center.x, y: pillar23.center.y)
    self.pillar25.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar24.center.x, y: pillar24.center.y)
    self.pillar26.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar25.center.x, y: pillar25.center.y)

    self.pillar.isHidden = false
    self.pillar2.isHidden = false
    self.pillar3.isHidden = false
    self.pillar4.isHidden = false
    self.pillar5.isHidden = false
    self.pillar6.isHidden = false
    self.pillar7.isHidden = false
    self.pillar8.isHidden = false
    self.pillar9.isHidden = false
    self.pillar10.isHidden = false
    self.pillar11.isHidden = false
    self.pillar12.isHidden = false
    self.pillar13.isHidden = false
    self.pillar14.isHidden = false
    self.pillar15.isHidden = false
    self.pillar16.isHidden = false
    self.pillar17.isHidden = false
    self.pillar18.isHidden = false
    self.pillar19.isHidden = false
    self.pillar20.isHidden = false
    self.pillar21.isHidden = false
    self.pillar22.isHidden = false
    self.pillar23.isHidden = false
    self.pillar24.isHidden = false
    self.pillar25.isHidden = false
    self.pillar26.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop2.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop3.isHidden = false
}
@IBAction func Retry(sender: Any) {
    self.viewDidLoad()
    self.Play(Play)
}

@IBOutlet var gameView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var pillar26: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar25: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar24: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar23: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar22: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar21: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar20: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar19: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar18: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar17: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar16: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar15: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar14: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar13: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar12: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar11: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar10: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreOnBoard: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreOnBoard: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
var timer = Timer()
var tapsValid:Bool?
var ballRight:Bool?
var ballChange:Bool?
var ballCenter: CGPoint?
var pillarCenter: CGPoint?
var pillar2Center: CGPoint?
var pillar3Center: CGPoint?
var pillar4Center: CGPoint?
var pillar5Center: CGPoint?
var pillar6Center: CGPoint?
var pillar7Center: CGPoint?
var pillar8Center: CGPoint?
var pillar9Center: CGPoint?
var pillar10Center: CGPoint?
var pillar11Center: CGPoint?
var pillar12Center: CGPoint?
var pillar13Center: CGPoint?
var pillar14Center: CGPoint?
var pillar15Center: CGPoint?
var pillar16Center: CGPoint?
var pillar17Center: CGPoint?
var pillar18Center: CGPoint?
var pillar19Center: CGPoint?
var pillar20Center: CGPoint?
var pillar21Center: CGPoint?
var pillar22Center: CGPoint?
var pillar23Center: CGPoint?
var pillar24Center: CGPoint?
var pillar25Center: CGPoint?
var pillar26Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTopCenter: CGPoint?
var pillarTop2Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTop3Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTop4Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTop5Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTop6Center: CGPoint?



@IBOutlet weak var scoreBoard: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var retry: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Ball: UIImageView!
//Start Screen
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.logo.isHidden = false
    self.Play.isHidden = false
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.pillar.isHidden = true
    self.pillar2.isHidden = true
    self.pillar3.isHidden = true
    self.pillar4.isHidden = true
    self.pillar5.isHidden = true
    self.pillar6.isHidden = true
    self.pillar7.isHidden = true
    self.pillar8.isHidden = true
    self.pillar9.isHidden = true
    self.pillar10.isHidden = true
    self.pillar11.isHidden = true
    self.pillar12.isHidden = true
    self.pillar13.isHidden = true
    self.pillar14.isHidden = true
    self.pillar15.isHidden = true
    self.pillar16.isHidden = true
    self.pillar17.isHidden = true
    self.pillar18.isHidden = true
    self.pillar19.isHidden = true
    self.pillar20.isHidden = true
    self.pillar21.isHidden = true
    self.pillar22.isHidden = true
    self.pillar23.isHidden = true
    self.pillar24.isHidden = true
    self.pillar25.isHidden = true
    self.pillar26.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop2.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop3.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop4.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop5.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop6.isHidden = true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if tapsValid == true
    {
        if ballRight == true
        {
            ballChange = false
        } else
        {
            ballChange = true
        }
    }
}

func movement()
{
    ballCenter = self.Ball.center
    pillarCenter = self.pillar.center
    pillar2Center = self.pillar2.center
    pillar3Center = self.pillar3.center
    pillar4Center = self.pillar4.center
    pillar5Center = self.pillar5.center
    pillar6Center = self.pillar6.center
    pillar7Center = self.pillar7.center
    pillar8Center = self.pillar8.center
    pillar9Center = self.pillar9.center
    pillar10Center = self.pillar10.center
    pillar11Center = self.pillar11.center
    pillar12Center = self.pillar12.center
    pillar13Center = self.pillar13.center
    pillar14Center = self.pillar14.center
    pillar15Center = self.pillar15.center
    pillar16Center = self.pillar16.center
    pillar17Center = self.pillar17.center
    pillar18Center = self.pillar18.center
    pillar19Center = self.pillar19.center
    pillar20Center = self.pillar20.center
    pillar21Center = self.pillar21.center
    pillar22Center = self.pillar22.center
    pillar23Center = self.pillar23.center
    pillar24Center = self.pillar24.center
    pillar25Center = self.pillar25.center
    pillar26Center = self.pillar26.center
    pillarTopCenter = self.pillarTop.center
    pillarTop2Center = self.pillarTop2.center
    pillarTop3Center = self.pillarTop3.center
    pillarTop4Center = self.pillarTop4.center
    pillarTop5Center = self.pillarTop5.center
    pillarTop6Center = self.pillarTop6.center


    if ballChange == false
    {
        ballRight = false
    } else
    {
        ballRight = true
    }
    if ballRight == true
    {
        Ball.center.x += 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }else
    {
        Ball.center.x -= 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }

    Ball.center.y += 0.5
    pillar.center.y += 5.0
    pillar2.center.y += 5.0
    pillar3.center.y += 5.0
    pillar4.center.y += 5.0
    pillar5.center.y += 5.0
    pillar6.center.y += 5.0
    pillar7.center.y += 5.0
    pillar8.center.y += 5.0
    pillar9.center.y += 5.0
    pillar10.center.y += 5.0
    pillar11.center.y += 5.0
    pillar12.center.y += 5.0
    pillar13.center.y += 5.0
    pillar14.center.y += 5.0
    pillar15.center.y += 5.0
    pillar16.center.y += 5.0
    pillar17.center.y += 5.0
    pillar18.center.y += 5.0
    pillar19.center.y += 5.0
    pillar20.center.y += 5.0
    pillar21.center.y += 5.0
    pillar22.center.y += 5.0
    pillar23.center.y += 5.0
    pillar24.center.y += 5.0
    pillar25.center.y += 5.0
    pillar26.center.y += 5.0

    pillar.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar.center.x, floaty: pillar.center.y, pillarNumber: 1)
    pillar2.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar2.center.x, floaty: pillar2.center.y, pillarNumber: 2)
    pillar3.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar3.center.x, floaty: pillar3.center.y, pillarNumber: 3)
    pillar4.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar4.center.x, floaty: pillar4.center.y, pillarNumber: 4)
    pillar5.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar5.center.x, floaty: pillar5.center.y, pillarNumber: 5)
    pillar6.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar6.center.x, floaty: pillar6.center.y, pillarNumber: 6)
    pillar7.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar7.center.x, floaty: pillar7.center.y, pillarNumber: 7)
    pillar8.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar8.center.x, floaty: pillar8.center.y, pillarNumber: 8)
    pillar9.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar9.center.x, floaty: pillar9.center.y, pillarNumber: 9)
    pillar10.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar10.center.x, floaty: pillar10.center.y, pillarNumber: 10)
    pillar11.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar11.center.x, floaty: pillar11.center.y, pillarNumber: 11)
    pillar12.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar12.center.x, floaty: pillar12.center.y, pillarNumber: 12)
    pillar13.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar13.center.x, floaty: pillar13.center.y, pillarNumber: 13)
    pillar14.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar14.center.x, floaty: pillar14.center.y, pillarNumber: 14)
    pillar15.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar15.center.x, floaty: pillar15.center.y, pillarNumber: 15)
    pillar16.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar16.center.x, floaty: pillar16.center.y, pillarNumber: 16)
    pillar17.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar17.center.x, floaty: pillar17.center.y, pillarNumber: 17)
    pillar18.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar18.center.x, floaty: pillar18.center.y, pillarNumber: 18)
    pillar19.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar19.center.x, floaty: pillar19.center.y, pillarNumber: 19)
    pillar20.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar20.center.x, floaty: pillar20.center.y, pillarNumber: 20)
    pillar21.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar21.center.x, floaty: pillar21.center.y, pillarNumber: 21)
    pillar22.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar22.center.x, floaty: pillar22.center.y, pillarNumber: 22)
    pillar23.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar23.center.x, floaty: pillar23.center.y, pillarNumber: 23)
    pillar24.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar24.center.x, floaty: pillar24.center.y, pillarNumber: 24)
    pillar25.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar25.center.x, floaty: pillar25.center.y, pillarNumber: 25)
    pillar26.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar26.center.x, floaty: pillar26.center.y, pillarNumber: 26)

    if (((Ball.center.x > pillarTop.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop2.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop2.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop2.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop2.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop3.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop3.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop3.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop3.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop4.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop4.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop4.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop4.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop5.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop5.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop5.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop5.center.y + 45)) ||
        ((Ball.center.x > pillarTop6.center.x - 50) && (Ball.center.x < pillarTop6.center.x + 50) && (Ball.center.y > pillarTop6.center.y - 45) && (Ball.center.y < pillarTop6.center.y + 45)))
    {

    }
    else
    {
    gameOverScreen()
    }
}
func movePillarUp(floatx: CGFloat, floaty: CGFloat, pillarNumber: Int) -> (CGPoint)
{

    var center = CGPoint(x: floatx,y: floaty)
    if checkPillarPosition(y: floaty) == true
    {
        switch pillarNumber
        {
        case 1:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar26.center.x, y: self.pillar26.center.y)
            break
        case 2:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar2)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar.center.x, y: self.pillar.center.y)
            break
        case 3:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar3)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar2.center.x, y: self.pillar2.center.y)
            break
        case 4:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar4)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar3.center.x, y: self.pillar3.center.y)
            break
        case 5:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar5)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar4.center.x, y: self.pillar4.center.y)
            break
        case 6:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar6)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar5.center.x, y: self.pillar5.center.y)
            break
        case 7:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar7)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar6.center.x, y: self.pillar6.center.y)
            break
        case 8:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar8)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar7.center.x, y: self.pillar7.center.y)
            break
        case 9:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar9)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar8.center.x, y: self.pillar8.center.y)
            break
        case 10:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar10)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar9.center.x, y: self.pillar9.center.y)
            break
        case 11:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar11)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar10.center.x, y: self.pillar10.center.y)
            break
        case 12:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar12)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar12.center.x, y: self.pillar12.center.y)
            break
        case 13:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar13)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar12.center.x, y: self.pillar12.center.y)
            break
        case 14:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar14)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar13.center.x, y: self.pillar13.center.y)
            break
        case 15:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar15)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar14.center.x, y: self.pillar14.center.y)
            break
        case 16:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar16)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar15.center.x, y: self.pillar15.center.y)
            break
        case 17:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar17)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar16.center.x, y: self.pillar16.center.y)
            break
        case 18:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar18)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar17.center.x, y: self.pillar17.center.y)
            break
        case 19:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar19)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar18.center.x, y: self.pillar18.center.y)
            break
        case 20:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar20)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar19.center.x, y: self.pillar19.center.y)
            break
        case 21:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar21)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar20.center.x, y: self.pillar20.center.y)
            break
        case 22:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar22)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar21.center.x, y: self.pillar21.center.y)
            break
        case 23:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar23)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar22.center.x, y: self.pillar22.center.y)
            break
        case 24:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar24)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar23.center.x, y: self.pillar23.center.y)
            break
        case 25:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar25)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar24.center.x, y: self.pillar24.center.y)
            break
        case 26:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar26)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar25.center.x, y: self.pillar25.center.y)
            break
        default:
            break

        }

    }
    return(center)
}

func gameOverScreen()
{
    tapsValid = false
    timer.invalidate()
    scoreLabel.isHidden = true
    gameOver.isHidden = false
    retry.isHidden = false
    scoreBoard.isHidden = false

    scoreOnBoard.isHidden = false
    highScoreOnBoard.isHidden = false

    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar2)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar3)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar4)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar5)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar6)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar7)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar8)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar9)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar10)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar11)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar12)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar13)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar14)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar15)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar16)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar17)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar18)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar19)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar20)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar21)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar22)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar23)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar24)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar25)
    gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar26)



}
func checkPillarPosition(y: CGFloat) -> (Bool)
{
    var low = false
    if y>720
    {
        low = true
    }
    return(low)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    if let newBallCenter = ballCenter{
        self.Ball.center = newBallCenter
    }
    if let newPillarCenter = pillarCenter{
        self.pillar.center = newPillarCenter
    }
    if let newPillar2Center = pillar2Center{
        self.pillar2.center = newPillar2Center
    }
    if let newPillar3Center = pillar3Center{
        self.pillar3.center = newPillar3Center
    }
    if let newPillar4Center = pillar4Center{
        self.pillar4.center = newPillar4Center
    }
    if let newPillar5Center = pillar5Center{
        self.pillar5.center = newPillar5Center
    }
    if let newPillar6Center = pillar6Center{
        self.pillar6.center = newPillar6Center
    }
    if let newPillar7Center = pillar7Center{
        self.pillar7.center = newPillar7Center
    }
    if let newPillar8Center = pillar8Center{
        self.pillar8.center = newPillar8Center
    }
    if let newPillar9Center = pillar9Center{
        self.pillar9.center = newPillar9Center
    }
    if let newPillar10Center = pillar10Center{
        self.pillar10.center = newPillar10Center
    }
    if let newPillar11Center = pillar11Center{
        self.pillar11.center = newPillar11Center
    }
    if let newPillar12Center = pillar12Center{
        self.pillar12.center = newPillar12Center
    }
    if let newPillar13Center = pillar13Center{
        self.pillar13.center = newPillar13Center
    }
    if let newPillar14Center = pillar14Center{
        self.pillar14.center = newPillar14Center
    }
    if let newPillar15Center = pillar15Center{
        self.pillar15.center = newPillar15Center
    }
    if let newPillar16Center = pillar16Center{
        self.pillar16.center = newPillar16Center
    }
    if let newPillar17Center = pillar17Center{
        self.pillar17.center = newPillar17Center
    }
    if let newPillar18Center = pillar18Center{
        self.pillar18.center = newPillar18Center
    }
    if let newPillar19Center = pillar19Center{
        self.pillar19.center = newPillar19Center
    }
    if let newPillar20Center = pillar20Center{
        self.pillar20.center = newPillar20Center
    }
    if let newPillar21Center = pillar21Center{
        self.pillar21.center = newPillar21Center
    }
    if let newPillar22Center = pillar22Center{
        self.pillar22.center = newPillar22Center
    }
    if let newPillar24Center = pillar24Center{
        self.pillar24.center = newPillar24Center
    }
    if let newPillar25Center = pillar25Center{
        self.pillar25.center = newPillar25Center
    }
    if let newPillar26Center = pillar26Center{
        self.pillar26.center = newPillar26Center
    }
    if let newPillarTopCenter = pillarTopCenter{
        self.pillarTop.center = newPillarTopCenter
    }
    if let newPillarTop2Center = pillarTop2Center{
        self.pillarTop2.center = newPillarTop2Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop3Center = pillarTop3Center{
        self.pillarTop3.center = newPillarTop3Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop4Center = pillarTop4Center{
        self.pillarTop4.center = newPillarTop4Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop5Center = pillarTop5Center{
        self.pillarTop5.center = newPillarTop5Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop6Center = pillarTop6Center{
        self.pillarTop6.center = newPillarTop6Center
    }
}
// This Function Places the Pillars
func pillarPlacement(x:CGFloat , y:CGFloat ) -> (CGPoint)
{
    var pillarNewX:CGFloat
    var pillarNewY:CGFloat

    var random:Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

    if random == 1
    {
        pillarNewX = x + 39
        pillarNewY = y - 29

        if pillarNewX  >= 319
        {
            pillarNewX = x-40
            pillarNewY = y-30
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pillarNewX = x - 40
        pillarNewY = y - 30

        if pillarNewX  <= 17
        {
            pillarNewX = x+39
            pillarNewY = y-29
        }
    }
    var newPillarCenter = CGPoint(x: pillarNewX,y:  pillarNewY)
    return(newPillarCenter)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I think it is telling me that when I click on the retry button something is being sent back incorrectly but I don't exactly know what is being sent incorrectly. If anyone could tell me whatever I did wrong, it would be gravely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the whole file containing the Retry function.

Comment: "[myApp.ViewController Retry:]" Where is written `Retry`? Not in ViewController.swift? AppDelegate code is useless. You can remove it from your question.

Comment: I had to delete the console message. Sorry about the unnecessary use of the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Florin's answer, but might get your solution faster, is if you remove the action attached to your button in your xib or storyboard (assuming you're using either), then re-attach targeting your Retry: method in your code.   If that doesn't help, please provide a screenshot of the action for this button on the InterfaceBuilder side.

Comment: That worked! Thank you a lot, I thought I already did that but I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you have the wrong function written as a selector for your retry button. Check it, also post the code from the viewcontroller file not the appdelegate.

Comment: Added it, but had to delete the console message.